# how to create a trigger that will run when any opportunity line item is added or deleted from the opportunity?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I am new to apex programming and trying to learn it these days. I want to create a trigger that will run every time an OLI is added or removed from the opportunity. Which standard object is appropriate too use for programming such a trigger.

Comment: You should definitely start at this [Apex Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Salesforce ERD. If you're using the native objects, the object is called the [OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm#!).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm

[image]

Comment: @RabiaIftikhar If you have additional questions, please open separate posts (make sure to read [ask]). Comments are for clarifications, not new questions. Please be aware that SFSE is not generally going to provide code specific to your requirements.

Comment: hello David, I am not asking for code I am just asking about which objects to use for writing this code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the OpportunityLineItem (label: Opportunity Product) object itself, and handle both `insert` and `delete` DML actions.